# Get the value of bootstrap Datetimepicker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I need to get the value of Datetimepicker in my JavaScript function. I have made something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#date").click( function(){
    alert(document.getElementById('datetimepicker1').value);
});
```

> It gives me 'undefined'

Comment: Refer this URL for usage: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Where have you got the datetime picker from?

Comment: Which datetimepicker is being used? From the first one I get with a Google search, I see that you should use: `$("#datetimepicker1").data("datetimepicker").getDate();`

Comment: @ Chris Moutray : from here http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Either use:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").data("datetimepicker").getDate();
```

Or (from looking at the page source):

```
$("#datetimepicker1").find("input").val();
```

The returned value will be a `Date` (for the first example above), so you need to format it yourself:

```
var date = $("#datetimepicker1").data("datetimepicker").getDate(),
    formatted = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
alert(formatted);
```

Also, you could just set the format as an attribute:

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="date">
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

and you could use the `$("#datetimepicker1").find("input").val();`

Comment: Thank you so much Ian
it gives me this now : Wed May 15 2013 21:45:37 GMT+0100 (WEST)
i need more help to convert this to mysql format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
sorry I'm very new to javascript

Comment: @Dxtr Cool, glad it helped :) I updated the answer once again that might be better - setting the format in the `data-format` attribute - it should automatically be displayed like that in the textbox

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind :
How to pass a javascript variable to jquery.get, like this

        Query.get('data.php&var1='var11, null, function(tsv) {

Comment: @Dxtr If `var11` contains the datetime you want to pass in the request, you'd use: `jQuery.get('data.php?var1=' + encodeURIComponent(var11), null, function`

Comment: I'm trying to get the date from a datetimepicker, your first line doesn't work I can only get it as a string. The suggestion in the below answer is also wrong and doesn't work. How do you claim you get the date?

Comment: `$("#item_location_form #vendor_cancel_date").find("input").val()` returns the value of datetimepicker

Answer (score 26):

It seems the doc evolved.

One should now use : 
`$("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date()`.

**NB** : Doing so return a [Moment object](http://momentjs.com/docs/), not a Date object

Answer (score 10):

To call the Bootstrap-datetimepikcer supported functions, you should use the syntax:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()
```

So you can try the function:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date();
```

Documentation: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/

Answer (score 5):

Or try:

```
$("#datetimepicker").data().date;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the return value has changed, `$("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date()` actually returns a moment object as Alexandre Bourlier stated:

> It seems the doc evolved.
>
> One should now use :  $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date().
>
> NB : Doing so return a Moment object, not a Date object

Therefore, we must use .toDate() to change this statement to a date as such:

`$("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date().toDate();`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the latest Bootstrap 3 DateTime Picker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

This is how you should use DateTime Picker inline:

```
var selectedDate = $("#datetimepicker").find(".active").data("day");
```

The above returned: 03/23/2017

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me using this [Bootsrap Datetimepiker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), it returns the value as it is shown in the datepicker input, e.g. `2019-04-11`

```
$('#myDateTimePicker').on('click,focusout', function (){
    var myDate = $("#myDateTimePicker").val();
    //console.log(myDate);
    //alert(myDate);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the above methods and I did not get the value properly in the same `format`, then I found this.

```
$("#datetimepicker1").find("input")[1].value;
```

*The above code will return the value in the same format as in the datetime picker.*

This may help you guys in the future.

Hope this was helpful..