# How to get datetime value from bootstrap datetime picker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Using Jquery and the Bootstrap Datetimepicker, how can I get the datetime value I selected using the Bootstrap Datepicker?
Here is the link of datetime picker I am using [datetime-picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline)

Here is my Html:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my j s:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true
    });
});
```

Comment: repeated que - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573624/get-the-value-of-bootstrap-datetimepicker-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Try calling the [date](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date)

```
$('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").date();
```

From docs:

> Returns the component's model current date, a moment object or null if
>   not set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change

```html
 <div id="datetimepicker12"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="selectedDate"></div>
```

You can get the value using input field id selector or you can get the value in form submission if that in inside a form

Comment: Your Answer is not correct..But your answer gave me a right direction..Thanks.

Comment: I am using "inline" type datetime picker and I don't have textbox.