# Get user's datetime chosen value using flatpickr

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, flatpickr

[Flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/#env-browser) has the option so that user can pick date/ datetime.

I m wondering how can I post user's chosen datetime to server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your html tag into a `<form>` and to set its name. That way if you post the `form`, you will be able to reach the value by the name attribute's value. I advise you to read about [html forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) if you choose this approach.

You can also send it via AJAX if you read the value. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573624/get-the-value-of-bootstrap-datetimepicker-in-javascript) is how you can read the value via Javascript. I advise you to read about [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) if you intend to use this approach.